# Correct Flattened Data Model and noSQL data structure

Tags: javascript, json, data-structures, firebase, data-modeling

I am currently building a small application using a service which requires and advocates the use of a "flattened" data model (the service is Firebase).

As I had no experience with data models before, I was wondering if I have flattened my data in a right way.

Here is a data model mockup which I started with (it has a lot of nested nodes):

```
// Core data model
    {
        // All registered users 
        "users": {
            // User assigned ID
            "userid": {
                // User information
                "password": "password",
                "email": "test@gmail.com",
                "name": "test",
                // Saved user entries
                "entries": {
                    // Entry ID
                    "entryid": {
                        // Firt part of entry
                        "first": {
                            "one": "yay",
                            "two": "nice",
                            "three": "man"
                        },
                        "second": {
                            "one": "wow",
                            "two": "hmm",
                            "three": "nope"
                        }
                    },

                    "entryid2": {
                        "first": {
                            "one": "kewl",
                            "two": "look",
                            "three": "this"
                       }
                    }
                }
            },
            "id2": {
                // ... and so on
            }
        }
    }
```

This is my "flattened" version:

```
// Flattened model
    {
        // All registered users 
        "users": {
            // User assigned ID
            "userid": {
                // User information
                "password": "password",
                "email": "test@gmail.com",
                "name": "test"
            },
            "userid2": {
                // ... and so on
            }
        },
        // All user entries
        "entries": {
            // User assigned UD (entries for particular user)
            "userid": {
                "first": {
                    "one": "yay",
                    "two": "nice",
                    "three": "man"
                },
                "second": {
                    "one": "kewl",
                    "two": "look",
                    "three": "this"
                }
            },
            "userid2": {
                "one": "wow",
                "two": "hmm",
                "three": "nope"
            }
        }
    }
```

It would be very helpful to know whether this is a correct (or at least possible) way of organising data in a flattened manner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is really no 100% right way to store data.  Its a combination of what works for you from a mental overhead perspective and the technical limitations of whatever store you are utilizing.

Although Firebase does advocate for a 'flat data structure' you are no where near their technical limits with either of your code samples.

From the [Understanding Data Docs](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/understanding-data.html):

> A child node's key cannot be longer than 768 bytes, nor deeper than 32
>   levels

You are only going a few nodes deep either way, I would suggest that you pick the data model that you can understand and communicate best as you are unlikely to run into a technical limitation within the scope you have posted above.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I know that at the current stage I am not hitting any technical limitations (and probably would not in the future with this particular project). 

However, my only concern would be is that Firebase indicates that there is a performance difference between two approaches used. More specifically in general (nested) approach every time a node is retrieved its child node are retrieved as well. Should I keep that in mind, or again, it only comes feasible at the higher levels of scale?

Comment: With Firebase if you query a node, you will get all the children of that node in the resulting snapshot. If it is a large node, there would be performance issues to consider. Is that the problem you are trying to solve?